Getting error while debugging the A-CAD code
A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. The debugger was configured to use the Desktop CLR (.NET Framework) Managed debugger, but the target process loaded the CoreCLR (.NET Core) runtime. To debug this project, configure it to use the 'Managed (CoreCLR)' debugger.
I tried giving the .exe path.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
